# Can I switch job with active L1b but with an approved and dormant h1b?

Tags: h1-visa, l1-visa

I am currently working on L1b visa. I was selected and approved h1b this year. I have the h1b dormant but remained on L1b.

I know that h1b allows me to switch jobs. With the dormant h1b can I change my employer? I heard I need to two payslips starting October.

Does this mean I have to activate my H1b?

Comment: how exactly is it dormant?